# Motion correction step for kalman filter

Tags: robotics, motion, kalman-filter, motionmodel

One way to predict the next state and covariance of a series of measurements is by using the [Kalman](https://vimeo.com/87854542) filter. In the context of tracking the position( the x and y coordinates) of a car in time, there is an issue which I did not find discussed anywhere. To simplify the problem lets suppose we have a single source that provides us measurements (a moving car), and we have to predict the next state(position) each time a new measurement comes. The Kalman filter first performs a prediction(to predict the next state) and then an update step(to correct the prediction with the actual measurement). What happens if the car moves at different speeds in different frames? I feel an extra step is missing. After the update step we would have to perform a correction of the position, because the prediction has been made with the assumption that the vehicle would have the same speed as it had until that point. Even though the update step brings the track closer to the actual measurement it doesn't align it perfectly to the measurement. 
Does anyone know how to solve such a motion correction issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the car moves at different speeds then the prediction covariance (uncertainty) is higher and adjust according to it. Also process noise (Q) refers to variance it may occur during process so if it happens frequently it needs to be adjusted to a higher value and so on.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment! Second, you are right regarding the noises in the process and measurement however that doesn't answer the question. I honestly think(and feel) that a motion compensation should be performed somehow...